# Streaming images with Nodejs on embedded device

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to stream images from a Node.js server to a client site. I've started with `socket.io`, but my implementation is fairly memory intensive (and possibly leaking as I'm not fluent in JavaScript). I'm just prototyping at this point with 10 sample images:

#### Server Side

Responds to a `socket.io` trigger with the following function that "streams" 10 images to the client at roughly 100ms intervals.

```
socket.on('img_trigger', function(data) {
    var img_num = 0;           
    var timeoutHandle = null;

    function startTimeout() {
        stopTimeout();
        if (img_num < 10) {
            timeoutHandle = setTimeout(updateStream, 100);
        }
    }

    function stopTimeout() {
        clearTimeout(timeoutHandle);
    }

    function updateStream() {
        var file = './sampleframes/sample-' + img_num + '.png';
        fs.readFile(file , function(err, file_buff) {
            if (err !== null) {
                console.log('readFile error: ' + err);
            } else {
                socket.emit('img_stream', { buffer: file_buff });
            }
            file_buff = null;
            ++img_num;
        });
        startTimeout();
    }
    // kicks off first image
    startTimeout();
});
```

#### Client Side

Capture the raw buffer data and generate a PNG with an `<img>` element.

```
socket.on('img_stream', function(data) {
    var img_data =  arrayBufferToBase64(data.buffer);
    var panel = $('#frame-panel');
    $('#frame').html('<img src="data:image/png;base64,' + 
        img_data + '" width="' + panel.width() + '" height="' +
        panel.height() + '" />');
});
```

If I trigger the server once, it works fine but not great. I notice the memory usage go up significantly, and it crashes after several triggers. Can I improve my code here to be efficient or should I try a new approach?

I've looked into using [Node's File Streams](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_createreadstream_path_options), [socket.io-streams](https://www.npmjs.com/package/socket.io-stream), and even [Binary.js](http://binaryjs.com/) (though I hesitate to require our clients to have too-modern of browsers) and they look promising, but I don't quite know which would be best for my use-case. Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

The web interface I'm developing is for an FPGA (Zynq-7000) based camera running PetaLinux with Node.js cross-compiled for the ARM processor, so I don't have a lot of server-side resources to work with. As such, I'd like to have the client-side do as much of the processing as possible. Eventually, streaming video would be incredible, but I'd be satisfied with reading and displaying successive frames at a reasonable rate.

Comment: How big are the images, and what is the increase in memory you are observing?

Comment: The images are each about 740KB, and the memory increase after 1 loop of 10 images was 18MB, and then 3 more loops were increases of about 28MB each. So after running through 40 images I was up more than 100MB.

Comment: You call `startTimeout` outside the `img_trigger` event - why?

Comment: @Sam, oh sorry. That's an error in my Stack Overflow formatting. I've corrected it. It actually calls `startTimeout` at the end of the function to kick off the first image.

Answer (score 0):

This may be due to a memory leak within the socket.io library (see [here](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/issues/1015) for a description, and [here](http://jpallen.net/2013/03/08/tracking-down-a-memory-leak-in-node-js-and-socket-io/) for a proposed fix).

To fix this, download and use the latest version of socket.io from [here](http://socket.io/download/).

Comment: If you are using the npm package manager, you can see which version of the package you have installed with npm list (or npm list -g).

Comment: Good suggestion, I saw the same post in my initial Google searches. But alas, I'm already on the latest version: `"socket.io": "^1.3.6"`.